# Express/Sequelize -- PUT Route to Update Form results in 500 Server Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on a put route in express to edit details for a book.  There are three required fields --title, author, genre.  If i go to edit the existing details of a book and remove one of the fields, instead of getting sequelize validation error, I get a 500 server error.  If i just try to change the text of a required field, it does update the database.  Here are my get and put routes for an individual book.

```
// Get book detail + loans
router.get("/details/:id", (req, res)=> {
     const book = Book.findById(req.params.id);
     const loans = Loan.findAll({where: {book_id: req.params.id}, include: [{ model: Patron}, {model: Book}]});

     Promise.all([book, loans]).then(function(data) {

     res.render('book_detail', {book: data[0], loans: data[1]});
  });
});

/* POST update book. */
router.put("/details/:id", function(req, res, next){
  Book.findById(req.params.id).then(function(book){
    if(book) {
      return book.update(req.body);
    } else {
      res.send(404);
    }
  }).then(function(book){
    res.redirect("/books/");
  }).catch(function(error){
      if(error.name === "SequelizeValidationError") {
        var book = Book.build(req.body);
        book.id = req.params.id;
        res.render("books/details/" + book.id, {book: book, errors: error.errors})
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
  }).catch(function(error){
      res.send(500, error);
   });
});
```

and this is what my PUG page looks like --using method override package to call PUT on the form string:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Book: #{title}

  include error

  form(action='/books/details/' + book.id + "?_method=PUT", method="post")
    P 
      label(for='title') Book Title:
      input(id='title' name='title' width="175" type='text' value=book.title)
    p
      label(for='author') Author:
      input(id='author' name='author' type='text' value=book.author)
    p
      label(for='genre') Genre:
      input(id='genre' name='genre' type='text' value=book.genre)
    p
      label(for='genre') First Published:
      input(id='first_published' name='first_published' type='text' value=book.first_published)
    p
      input(type='submit', value='Update')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the actual error message too. I.e. `console.log(error);`.

Comment: hey there the only error i'm getting is 500--internal sever error

Comment: You mean in the browser? I am thinking of the error message you see in the terminal if you add the console.log I mentioned right above `res.send(500, error);`.

Comment: yeah i tried that too, and not giving me much information at all.  just this: 1:1 POST http://localhost:3000/books/details/1?_method=PUT 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

`router.post` and `router.put` are different, make sure you send the right kind of request. Since you send a `POST` request from your page, this request will handle by `router.post`, not `router.put`, so this 500 error is throw from the `router.post`. As `PUT` is not allowed in html form, you should think another way to update your book.

Comment: thanks for reply—I’m using method override package which allows for put request in form—https://github.com/expressjs/method-override